# Keychain says "Access to this item is restricted" after upgrading to Lion

Tags: macos, password, permission

I recently upgraded to Lion and since then I haven't been able to use Keychain to look at my stored passwords.  When I click on the checkbox to show them it prompts me for my master password, then pops up a dialog that says "Access to this item is restricted".

Based on reading questions here and on other support sites, I've tried using the Keychain Access program's "Keychain First Aid" feature.  It reports that there are no errors.  I also used Disk Utility to Repair Disk Permissions, and this didn't fix the problem either.

I looked in ~/Library/Keychains/ and it looks like I do have owner permission to read and write the keychain file, and my main account is the owner.

Is there anything else I can try to fix this?  I'd hate to lose my keychain passwords.

Update:

I also tried dragging my login.keychain file from Finder into Keychain Access, and had no luck.  I tried some digging around in the security command line app as well, but have made no progress...

Update 2:

After trying all the suggestions I commented on here I was still getting this error, but then I did a software update, and rebooted, and now my keychain is working again.  So, I have no idea what went wrong, but it is now fixed!  I'll just pick an answer as accepted.

Comment: I had the same problem what I found is it is somehow linked to not being on the Internet and the time and date were not updated once I changed it to correct time and date rebootEd and it allowed me access back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several reasons Keychain does this. Often it's because a new account that you might have switched to does not have the same/correct paths to Keychain that it used to. For starters try changing the main login password of your account; if that doesn't do anything try this in terminal:

```
$ sudo touch login.keychain
$ codesign -vvv /Applications/Utilities/Keychain\ Access.app
```

If you get an error such as:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app: code or signature modiﬁed
```

then:

```
$ codesign -vvv /Applications/Utilities/Keychain\ Access.app
```

which should give you the response:

```
/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app: valid on disk
/Applications/Utilities/Keychain Access.app: satisﬁes its Designated Requirement
```

Reboot.

Comment: These seem like great suggestions, unfortunately, they didn't fix it.  I haven't changed accounts, but I tried touching the login.keychain, changing my password, and codesign (which gives me "valid" and "satisfies" output).  Still gives the same error.

Comment: I forgot to mention rebooting; I'm happy to see that it worked. ;-)

Comment: @Lri, `-vvv` increments the verbosity level of output ([EXAMPLES](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html)), so yes it DOES do something. The goal of the chosen commands are to adjust the timestamp on the login keychain and verify the existing signature with verbose output. `-f -s` would force replace any existing signature on the path to be replaced and signed; why would you do that? Take a look at the man pages to get better idea of codesign concepts.

Answer (score 13):

Does running the command-line version of Keychain:

```
security dump-keychain -d login.keychain
```

also fail, but with the weird message `In dark wake, no UI possible`?

Then part of Mac OS is [confused about whether it is asleep or not](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/107603/11282). There’s no need to reboot. Put it to sleep, wake it up, and Keychain should be fine again. This happens on my MacBook Pro sometimes: I open it to wake it, press the power button out of habit, only to turn it off as it is trying to start up, resulting in weird Keychain behaviour.

Answer (score 11):

this worked for me - open Keychain access, click the lock to lock the keychains, then unlock again!

Answer (score 3):

For starters Keychain has a nifty little tool called: "Keychain first aid" (⌥⌘A) which should do the trick. After completion you do need to logout and login again.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me:

- Open keychain access
- Run the Keychain first aid (⌥⌘A)
- Restart mac

I tried a couple approaches noted above and none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are a MobileMe user?

I had the same issues.  If you are still using/syncing MobileMe on a 10.6.8 or earlier Mac, then you're probably best to stop.  It seems that the certificates issued from Snow and Lion are not entirely compatible.

Make a copy of your Keychain, then in Keychain Access, delete everything that has .mac or MobileMe in its name and restart.  The MobileMe certificates will be repopulated and you should be okay.

If that fails, then try just dragging your old Keychain into the Keychain pane of Keychain Access.  You will then have a new Keychain, separate from your Login Keychain, which will have to be unlocked for use.  Once things are working okay, you can drag the items from here into your Login Keychain.  You may find that some still will not give you permission to access.  I had one or two like this and in the end, just re-did them manually.

Comment: I am not a mobile me user, but I'll try the trick of dragging my old keychain into Keychain Access.

Comment: For the record, this didn't work.  Dragging the login.keychain file into the Keychains pane doesn't do anything, and dragging into the main pane where the data is tells me I don't have permission.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem after an El Capitan upgrade (10.11.2). **Access to this item is restricted Error 253200.** Only some passwords were unobtainable. Here is what I did to solve the problem.

In El Capitan there is NO Keychain First Aid feature. Disk Utility can NO longer be used to Repair Disk Permissions (you can do this from the command line but is not helpful in this case). Much advice on the Internet is thus OUT OF DATE hence this note.

- I used Keychain Access > Preferences / General to Reset my default
  login keychain.
- I quit Keychain Access
- I  opened the ~/Library/Keychains/
- I entered Time Machine
- I went back to a time before the likely corruption (in my case the
  10.11.2 upgrade)
- I restored the login.keychain item
- I did not replace but added the file and renamed it old.keychain.
- I opened it using keychain access. I could now read my old passwords.
- I did have to re-enter passwords - including for Mail. Note that you
  will need to re-enter passwords for the smtp servers too

Answer (score 1):

Keychain says “Access to this item is restricted”

As posted by Matt:  This worked for me as well.

- open Keychain access, click the lock to lock the keychains, then unlock again! -

Its the simplest least potentially destructive option and I was very sceptical, but it worked. So worth a shot as it takes seconds. I'm running OS X El Capitan V 10.11.6

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Unfortunately, this is commentary in response to someone else's commentary on a different answer and in and of itself, doesn't actually provide an answer to the question.  "Answers" are for what directly addresses the question posted by the OP.  To better help acclimate you to the site, I suggest taking a moment to review the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

On Mojave, with error code "-25320", the fix was to put the system to sleep and re-wake it. That's it! No reboot or permission changes necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I was in the keychain access menu and clicked on my network to open it, I got the "access is restricted" message when, on the far left, the "login" icon was highlighted. However, if, on the far left, the "system" icon was highlighted, I was able to retrieve my password for the network I selected. No reboot necessary. I hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same message.  First I tried the ***Keychain First Aid*** which found nothing wrong.  I then went to the ***Disk Utility*** and selected the ***Macintosh HD*** and ran ***Repair Disk Permissions***, then went back to the **Keychain First Aid** and ran it again, still did not show anything wrong BUT, now my Keychain is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped was going to the Access Control tab for that specific entry of Keychain Access and selecting Allow All Applications to access this item. Once I had set that up, it worked.

[image]