# Keychain: Secure Notes: Access to this item is restricted

Tags: keychain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keychain says “Access to this item is restricted” after upgrading to Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25321/keychain-says-access-to-this-item-is-restricted-after-upgrading-to-lion)

I recently did a clean install on my MacBook pro. Before I did the clean install, I backed up what I thought would be the keychain stuff. This is what I backed up. I used a back up program called ibackup and I selected keychain to back it up. I also copied the keychain folder, which was located in the Macintosh Hard drive in the Library folder, and also I backed up the folder, which was in the other Library folder in the System folder.

I then copy all the backed up content back into those folders. I can access the keychain and my entire login passwords with out any problems. I can see the secure notes are there that I created but once I try to open then so I can see contents of the secure notes I get this error “Access to this item is restricted”

I hoping I can access my secure notes again. I want to mention once I do a restart it seems like my keychain secure notes resets it self and I have no secure notes in the keychain anymore. I hope someone can help.

Thanks