# What prevents export of a private key from Mavericks keychain?

Tags: sleep-wake, macos, keychain

In Mac OS X Mavericks, I'm not able to export a private key from keychain. I'm getting the following error message:
 **/* In dark wake, no UI possible */**

Searching it in Apple documentation fetched the following details:

**value: -25320**

**Description: The user interface could not be displayed because the system is in a dark wake state. Available in OS X v10.7 and later.**

Can someone please suggest a solution or the cause of problem?

Comment: How are you doing the export? The error code would suggest that you’re doing it through, e.g. an ssh login or some other non-interactive method.

Comment: doing from keychain, by right clicking on the key and selecting export.

Comment: Hmm, it appears your system was mistaken about being asleep, then. Does a reboot fix the issue?

Comment: yes. reboot fixed the issue. I am now able to export the key. Dont know why it happened in the first place.

Comment: @microtherion Please answer this question so that it can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 7):

It appears that your system was mistaken about being asleep (because an internal flag it used to keep track of sleep state got out of sync with the true state). As you confirmed later, a reboot fixes this problem.

Comment: **Sleep-then-wake-up** also fix this problem.